# How to do git copy merge from one branch to other

Tags: git, github, merge, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

How do I copy merge from branch to other. Let's say I have a branch A and B. I want to do copy merge from B to A. I.e. Ignore all changes done on branch A and simply copy all change from B to A.

Copy merge should delete new files folders on branch A if created on A only. Other way we can say simply copy B to A without conflict or a simple OS cp command.

How can I achieve this on GIT?

Also what will be the difference if branch B is master?

Answer (score 0):

To merge A with B and have it look exactly like B, merge A into B (not the other way round) with the `ours` strategy. So, checkout B, and say `git merge -s ours A`. As the documentation says:

> The resulting tree of the merge is always that of the current branch head, effectively ignoring all changes from all other branches. It is meant to be used to supersede old development history of side branches.

Comment: So, we have to this, am I correct. Sorry very new to GIT.

Git clone;

git checkout B;

git merge -s ours A;

git push;

git checkout A;

git merge B;

git push;

Comment: Also can we do same when branch B is master?